# Disabling email sender from View

Tags: asp.net-core, notifications

in my .net core app in controller I am building body of email then it calls email sender service where whole email is built and send via SMTP specified in startup. Sender service is the ordinary one nothing special. Everything works flawlessly and my notifications are sent with 100% success. But... there are time I don't want to send notifications in production enviroment. Is there any way how to turn off email sender from View? I can imagine, turning it off on each specific view which causes the notification but I can live with turning it off and on for whole app.

Comment: What do you mean by *Sender service is the ordinary one*? What exactly is this?

Comment: it is smtpClient()

Comment: One option is to use an abstraction around the email service and then inject either the real one or a [Null Object](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/null_object) version when the application starts.